# How to remove a row after adding it to a view object with createRow()

Tags: java, oracle, commit, oracle-adf

I have a view object and I create a row like this:

```
ContactsVORowImpl person = ( ContactsVORowImpl ) getContactsVO().createRow();
```

Then I assign some of the properties of the created row, leaving others unassigned (deliberately):

```
        person.setFirstname( "firstname" );
        //person.setLastname( "" );
        person.validate();
```

I get a validation error complaining because `Lastname` is null.

Then I commit anyway, **WITHOUT** inserting the row into the view object:

```
getDBTransaction().commit();
```

Here I get the following exception for `Lastname` being null:

```
  Exception Class:  class oracle.jbo.AttrValException,  Message: JBO-27014: The attribute Lastname in ContactsEO is needed.
| oracle.jbo.AttrValException: JBO-27014: The attribute Lastname in ContactsEO is needed.
  at oracle.jbo.server.JboMandatoryAttributesValidator.validate(JboMandatoryAttributesValidator.java:224)
  at oracle.jbo.server.EntityDefImpl.validate(EntityDefImpl.java:3200)
  at oracle.jbo.server.EntityCache.validate(EntityCache.java:3601)
  at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.validateEntity(EntityImpl.java:2361)
  at oracle.jbo.server.EntityImpl.validate(EntityImpl.java:2540)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.validate(DBTransactionImpl.java:4540)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.commitInternal(DBTransactionImpl.java:2035)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.commit(DBTransactionImpl.java:2378)
```

1. How can this happen, since I didn't insert the row?
2. How can I work around this?

I am actually doing a group commit; I am detecting defective rows and not inserting them in the view object to avoid the commit. Nevertheless it tries to commit them; why?

Comment: What do you want? Call commit without commit?

Comment: I need to call a group commit, to commit other created and inserted  rows, but not this one (the faulty ones), so why do I get an error on this commit, when we don't even have an inserted row . . .

Comment: I don't understand the 2 close votes

Comment: Are you looking for [_nested_ transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_transaction)?

Comment: You can't commit some rows/change within a single transaction. It's all or nothing.

Comment: @User404 Yes I know that, But the thing here is that I didn't insert the row in the view object yet, so initially the commit must not consider it in the commiting process, but abruptly it does . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states:

> Creates a new view row. The new row is not placed in the entity cache
>   until its primary key is initialized. It is inserted into the database
>   when changes are posted to database and the transaction is committed.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e10653/oracle/jbo/server/ViewObjectImpl.html#createRow()

The last part seems to say that it's inserted into the database, so that's the reason you get the exception.

Workaround: Try to call `removeCurrentRow` but before check if the current row is the row you just created. NOT TESTED.

Comment: I tried that and it gives an exception saying that the row is dead